# Why do most enum values end with BUTT specifier in declaration?

Tags: java, c++, c, enums, coding-style

While reading most of the open-source code, I frequently see that `enum` values end with a `_BUTT` specifier? It may sound naive, but is there any significance for such coding style?

Example 1:

```
typedef enum __nvp1114a_samplerate {
        NVP1114A_8000,
        NVP1114A_16000,
        NVP1114A_32000,
        NVP1114A_44100,
        NVP1114A_48000,
        NVP1114A_BUTT
} nvp1114a_samplerate;
```

Example 2:

```
typedef enum hiVIDEO_NORM_E
{
    VIDEO_ENCODING_MODE_PAL=0,
    VIDEO_ENCODING_MODE_NTSC,
    VIDEO_ENCODING_MODE_AUTO,
    VIDEO_ENCODING_MODE_BUTT
} VIDEO_NORM_E;
```

Comment: So you can symbolically specify the amount of possible values in the enum.

Comment: Its the count of the values

Comment: I have never seen this in Java, nor would it make sense as `enum` in Java are objects not integers.

Comment: don't understand the downvotes, what is the problem with the question?

Comment: @sp2danny Perhaps most netizens here on SO suffer from `Hundredth monkey effect` where one previously learned behavior/downvote instantly spreads across all fellow netizens.

Comment: Seems like a valid question, but it is not a valid question in the context of Java so that tag should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the last `_BUTT` constant is the number of constants (excluding the `_BUTT` one) in the enumerated type.

This last constant is not required and its presence as well as its naming is just a personal choice of the programmer.

Comment: But why this information is required to be inside enum declaration?

Comment: @Manav it is *not* required.

Comment: I don't think `_BUTT` will be much useful for error checking, but I can use it to loop over all enum values.

Comment: Re: error checking, it can be used to check if an integer value is in range for the enum.

Comment: if you have it last inside the enum, it updates automatically when you add values